# failing migrations : PG::ProtocolViolation Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-migrations, rails-postgresql

I just updated to rails4 and realized that my db roles and database was somehow not setup.

So I dropped the db and re-created the app_development db and the roles.

Now I am trying to run rake db:migrate and its failing with following error:

```
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0081s
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0031s
-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0030s
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrated (0.0144s) =====================================

rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR:  bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "a1" requires 0
: INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ('20130815235601')
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

**I tried to run migrations for different tables manually and it gives the same for each table.**

Here is a sample migration file that it is complaining about:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      ## Token authenticatable
      # t.string :authentication_token


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

I think one way is to delete the migration and re-create it.

But I am not sure of exact steps to do that.

Can anyone help me with exact steps with getting the migrations running. I dont mind dropping the db etc since the project is dev stage and there is not much prod data/schema I need to worry about

Thanks.
Rails 4.0
PG 9.3.0

---

**Update1:**
Dont see any rows in schema_mgrations:

```
select * from schema_migrations;
version
---------
(0 rows)
```

---

**Update2:**
Inserting by hand the same values works fine !

```
INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ('20130815235601');
INSERT 0 1

select * from schema_migrations
    version
----------------
 20130815235601
```

### (1 row)

**Update 3**

I ran migrations for different table manually and its failing for each table, so its not an issue with any specific migration.

I also tried to revert back to Rails 3.2.14 and am still facing the same issue.

Feeling lost here and stuck in it for 4-5 days now !!

Comment: Your migration isn't the problem, the problem happens when Rails tries to remember that it has run your migration. The `schema_migrations` table tracks which migrations have been run in its `version` column and an INSERT for `schema_migrations` is triggering the exception. Wild guess: have you upgraded your PostgreSQL libraries but not rebuilt your `pg` gem?

Comment: I am using PG gem and have changed it in the Gemfile, but I did drop the db and now am trying to rerun the migrations

Comment: And everything works now? Could be a Heisenbug.

Comment: Its happening again. Is there a way to simply clear and rerun all migrations from the start. using db:drop, db:create, db:migrate ends up with same issue. Also the schema_migrations table is empty

Comment: Have you rebuilt your `pg` gem? If this was a bug in the Rails4 PostgreSQL driver we'd be seeing a lot more questions about it, the lack of complaints suggests that you have something odd in your set up. What have you changed recently?

Comment: I uninstalled pg gem and bundled again. There has to be a way to just remove all the migrations and re-run them from scratch !